# How to move team services backlog work items to another tenant

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to move the backlog items and any related linked items to another tenant, any ideas?

Comment: With tenant, you mean another VSTS account? Or another Team Project or Team?

Comment: Another VSTS account.

Comment: why want to move ? you know you can rename a tenant?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in that does this.

You'll either have to write your own solution or look into one of the various migration or integration tools that are available on the market. None of them provide full fidelity migration, however.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said that there isn’t built-in tool.

You can build an application with REST API to create the new workitems per to the workitems in another VSTS. Regarding Work Item creating REST API, there is bypass rules that can remain System.CreatedDate and System.CreatedBy value: [Make an update bypassing rules](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#make-an-update-bypassing-rules).

On the other hand, there is 3rd tool: [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility)